# Is there a commonly used term for a number divided by its greatest common divisor?

Tags: terminology, gcd-and-lcm

Does the expression $\frac{a}{\gcd(a, b)}$ have a common name?

This type of expression occurs frequently in a program I'm writing. Since $ \forall a,b \in \mathbb{N^{*}}: \frac{a}{\gcd(a, b)} \perp \frac{b}{\gcd(a, b)}$, I've been calling this the coprime part or coprime residue of $a$ relative to $b$. I'd prefer to use a term of art if one exists.

Comment: You might like to check "additive order" of a positive integer.

Comment: Additive order over the integers seems like exactly what I was looking for. Wanna make this an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you were looking for **additive order**.

Let $a\in\mathbb{Z}_n$. Then, the **smallest positive solution** of the congruence 
$ax\equiv0\pmod{n}$ is called **additive order** of $a$, which is given by ${n\over gcd(a,n)}$.